# FileNotFoundException when starting java

Tags: java, linux, timezone

I am starting an application with remote debug and suspend on start turned on.
When I connect remotely to the process, I getting stopped in an uncaught `FileNotFoundException` in `ZoneInfo.getTimeZone()`
It is cause by the line: `new PatternLayout("[%d{HH:mm:ss}] %-5p: %m%n")`.
apparently java is not finding timezone for *Israel* in *jre/lib/zi* directory.
I appreciate if you know how to fix it.
Thanks.

Edit: It appears the problem is that time zone is defined as "Israel" and Java only have "Asia/Jerusalem" time zone.
How can It be changed on linux machine?

Comment: It runs perfectly with another timezone?

Comment: Didnt tested it on another time-zone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I found so far this is an inconsistency between suse 10 os and java. the os calls the time zone "(GMT+2:00) Israel" while java expects "(GMT+2:00) Jerusalem".
There is a workaround - starting java with the flag `-Duser.timezone=Asia/Jerusalem` or `-Duser.timezone=GMT+2`. the second option is not good for daylight savings. more details on [this blog](http://markbramnik.blogspot.com/2010/03/java-dates.html).

Answer (score 1):

Israeli time zone should be Asia/Jerusalem. I see it under my jre/lib/zi.

I believe that there can be 2 reasons for failure of your program:

- this file does not exist on your system.
- something is wrong in definition of time zone on your computer.

So,

- Check if the file Jerusalem is there
- Check what is the default time zone returned by TimeZone.getDefault() and what is configured on control panel.

Comment: I have the Asia/Jerusalem. TimeZone.getDefault() returns Israel. the machine is linux, so is it a bug in the linux configuration?